# Running a CAD viewer from server

Tags: viewer, cad

Basically I'm looking for something that will allow users to open and modify dwf files in their browser (like the Autodesk Design Review allows users to open files in IE). But is there such a probgram that will run from a server, without the user having to install anything on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

That may be impossible. You can use VRML, supported by asp.net.